# push an associative arrays as a one associative array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, associative-array

I have this desired associative array format (refer below)

```
$url = array (
    "a1" => array(
        'k1' => "content of k1 in a1 array",
        'k2' => "content of k2 in a1 array"
    ),
    "a2" => array(
        'k1' => "content of k1 in a2 array",
        'k2' => "content of k2 in a2 array"
    ),
);
```

and in Laravel thing, I retrieved a records in a database table and loop on it and then get its value and push it unto an array.

```
$k = kk::with('kk_names')->get();
$k_array = array();
foreach($k as $item){
    $sr = array($item->name => array("k1" => $item->items[0]->description,"k2" => $item->items[1]->description))
array_push($k_array,$sr);
}
```

it did works but the associative array format (refer above associative array format) was not the one I want, it gives me this instead.

```
$url = array (
    array("a1" => array(
        'k1' => "content of k1 in a1 array",
        'k2' => "content of k2 in a1 array"
    )),
    array("a2" => array(
        'k1' => "content of k1 in a2 array",
        'k2' => "content of k2 in a2 array"
    )),
);
```

any ideas, help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`array_push` push element onto the end of `array`. You are doing like -

```
array_push(array(...), array($item->name => ...));
```

Which would give -

```
array (
   array($item->name => ...),
   array($item->name => ...)
)
```

But according to your desired output, you want `$item->name` to be the index and array('k1' ...) to be the elements.

You can do simply -

```
foreach($k as $item) {
    $k_array[$item->name] = array(
        "k1" => $item->items[0]->description,
        "k2" => $item->items[1]->description
    );
}
```

Comment: so how do you put it on a loop and array push?

Comment: @CodeDemon Check the updated code. You can put that previous code inside the loop and it would work.

Comment: Gald to help.. :) Just dont forget to accept if it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `foreach` loop do this instead.

```
foreach($k as $item){    
   $k_array[$item->name] = array(
        "k1" => $item->items[0]->description,
        "k2" => $item->items[1]->description
    )
}
```

and you don't need to use the `array_push($k_array,$sr);`